# How to freeze part of the weights in a layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I implemented a custom regularizer `my_reg`. During the training, I hope I can have such feature: randomly freeze **part of** the parameters, like a Dropout, but only applies to this regularizer:

```py
class my_reg(Regularizers):
    def __call__(self, loss):
        freeze_param = self.p[randomly_choose]
        freeze_param.trainable = False
```

How can I randomly choose from those parameters and freeze them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to freeze weights in certain layer with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059529/how-to-freeze-weights-in-certain-layer-with-keras)

Comment: @meowongac Its not a duplicate of that question, here the OP asks to freeze some weights in a layer, not all of them. I think this has been asked before anyways.